# Get data from datagrid to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an usercontrol containing DataGrid (datagrid allow user edit on grid), but when i get collection data from datagrid through viewmodel property, but collection only get number of row but not get datagrid content.

View

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day" Binding="{Binding Monday}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel

```
public class RuleDetailViewModel : UserControlViewModelBase
{
    ObservableCollection<RuleDetailExpViewModel> _ruleDetailList;

    public RuleDetailViewModel()
    {
        _ruleDetailList = new ObservableCollection<RuleDetailExpViewModel> 
        { 
            new RuleDetailExpViewModel(), 
            new RuleDetailExpViewModel() 
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RuleDetailExpViewModel> RuleDetailList
    {
        get { return _ruleDetailList; }
        set 
        { 
             _ruleDetailList = ruleDetailList;
            OnPropertyChanged("RuleDetailList");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried ItemsSource="{Binding RuleDetailList}" and ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding RuleDetailList}" but unsucessfully.

How can i get data from view to viewmodel?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your view to

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RuleDetailList}" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day" Binding="{Binding Monday}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the `RuleDetailExpViewModel` must contain the property `Monday`

Comment: I tried ItemsSource="{Binding RuleDetailList}" and ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding RuleDetailList}" but unsucessfully

Comment: i tried it now and it works fine just change ruleDetailList with value